# How to remove the Square Bracket from JSON using arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this Array (full code):

```
<?php
    //Enter your code here, enjoy!

    $array1 = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++){
        $array1[] = array(
            "key1$i" => "value1$i",
            "key2$i" => "value2$i",
            "key3$i" => "value3$i"
        );
    }

    $array2 = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++){
        $array2[$i]["key4$i"] = "value4$i";
        $array2[$i]["key5$i"] = "value4$i";
        $array2[$i]["key6$i"] = "value4$i";
    }

    $data =  array(
            "Father"     => array(
                "Mother"         => array(array( 
                    "KeyA"       => "VALUEA",
                    "KeyB"       => "VALUEB",
                    "KeyC"       => "VALUEC",
                    "KeyD"       => "VALUED",
                ),
                array(
                    "Key1"       => "VALUE1",
                    "Key2"       => "VALUE2",
                    "Key3"       => "VALUE3",
                    "Key4"       => "VALUE4",
                ),
                array(
                    "Key5"       => "VALUE5",
                    "Key6"       => "VALUE6",
                    "Key7"       => "VALUE7",
                    "Key8"       => "VALUE8",
                ),

                $array1,

                $array2,

                array(
                    "Key9"        => "VALUE9",
                    "Key10"       => "VALUE10",
                    "Key11"       => "VALUE11",
                    "Key12"       => "VALUE12",
                ),

            ))
        );

        $json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

        echo $json;
```

I create 2 arrays dynamically and the rest are static.

The problem is that when I create the JSON, the structure gets damaged and the petition doesn't work.

The result is:

```
{
    "Father": {
        "Mother": [
            {
                "KeyA": "VALUEA",
                "KeyB": "VALUEB",
                "KeyC": "VALUEC",
                "KeyD": "VALUED"
            },
            {
                "Key1": "VALUE1",
                "Key2": "VALUE2",
                "Key3": "VALUE3",
                "Key4": "VALUE4"
            },
            {
                "Key5": "VALUE5",
                "Key6": "VALUE6",
                "Key7": "VALUE7",
                "Key8": "VALUE8"
            },
            [   // REMOVE THIS
                {
                    "key10": "value10",
                    "key20": "value20",
                    "key30": "value30"
                },
                {
                    "key11": "value11",
                    "key21": "value21",
                    "key31": "value31"
                }
            ],   // REMOVE THIS
            [   // REMOVE THIS
                {
                    "key40": "value40",
                    "key50": "value40",
                    "key60": "value40"
                },
                {
                    "key41": "value41",
                    "key51": "value41",
                    "key61": "value41"
                }
            ],   // REMOVE THIS
            {
                "Key9": "VALUE9",
                "Key10": "VALUE10",
                "Key11": "VALUE11",
                "Key12": "VALUE12"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see it closes the 2 dynamically generated Arrays in square brakets.

I tried creating it with old school arrays and with asociative arrays (as seen in the code example) and none seem to work.

The JSON output I need is:

```
{
    "Father": {
        "Mother": [
            {
                "KeyA": "VALUEA",
                "KeyB": "VALUEB",
                "KeyC": "VALUEC",
                "KeyD": "VALUED"
            },
            {
                "Key1": "VALUE1",
                "Key2": "VALUE2",
                "Key3": "VALUE3",
                "Key4": "VALUE4"
            },
            {
                "Key5": "VALUE5",
                "Key6": "VALUE6",
                "Key7": "VALUE7",
                "Key8": "VALUE8"
            },
            {
                "key10": "value10",
                "key20": "value20",
                "key30": "value30"
            },
            {
                "key11": "value11",
                "key21": "value21",
                "key31": "value31"
            },
            {
                "key40": "value40",
                "key50": "value40",
                "key60": "value40"
            },
            {
                "key41": "value41",
                "key51": "value41",
                "key61": "value41"
            },
            {
                "Key9": "VALUE9",
                "Key10": "VALUE10",
                "Key11": "VALUE11",
                "Key12": "VALUE12"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can test the code in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ (copying the first box I put). I would share it here but the webpage seems to be down for saving and sharing codes. Onces it is up I will update this thread.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you are missing the $i in your first for loop inside []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge) to append the elements.

```
$data['Father']['Mother'] = array_merge($data['Father']['Mother'], $array1, $array2);
```

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much for your help @shingo!

Answer (score 2):

It's because $array1 and $array2 are array of array instead of simple array.
Change the `$array2[$i]["key4$i"] = "value4$i";` by `$array2["key4$i"] = "value4$i";` and it will be all good :]

The `[]` in Json are the syntaxe for a collections (array) where the `{}` are the syntaxe for objects and associative arrays.

***Update :*** 
You can merge your array :

With an overwrite

```
$array1[0] = "zero";
$array1[1] = "one";

$array2[1] = "one";
$array2[2] = "two";

$arr3 = $arr1 + $arr2;
//Will result $array3 = array(0=>"zero", 1=>"one", 2=>"two");
```

Or without, depending of your need :

```
$array1[0] = "zero";
$array1[1] = "one";

$array2[1] = "one";
$array2[2] = "two";

$arr3 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
//Will result $array3 = array(0=>"zero", 1=>"one", 2=> "one", 2=>"two");
```

Comment: Ok I see your point but in my application, my problem is that the keys are the same for that structure say:

$array2['user'] = "Jhon"
$array2['pass'] = "xxx"

$array2['user'] = "Maria"
$array2['pass'] = "YYY"

In this case Jhon would overwrite Maria wouldnt it?

Comment: What about making a specified key only for this type of entries? I don't have the detail for all your logic so hard to say. So probably a special ID or taking the length of the array and adding +1 to be sure to not overwrite.